# Ubuntu 14.04 OS Keyboard Shortcuts Caught by Programs

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I am trying to set alt+a to a keyboard shortcut within system preferences > keyboard shortcuts. I click to the shortcut I want to set so that it says "new accelerator," but hitting alt+a sends me back to the main systems preferences menu. I am seeing this in a number of places, where alt+s will open the history menu of firefox, when instead I want it to run my own keyboard shortcut. I had no problems with setting these things when using 13.10, it seems 14.04 has broken it.

I want to be able to bind whatever key I chose to the shortcut I chose, and override program specific keyboard shortcuts. How can I do this in 14.04?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Just to clarify the question:  it is possible to set Alt-s as a keyboard shortcut, and it works most of the time, but if a firefox window has focus, then Alt-s brings up firefox's History menu instead of doing the action I have assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it with `dconf-editor`.

Go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys and edit manually your keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any custom keybindings under media-keys. It doens't have a drop down menu, its selectable and on the side window there is a bunch of stuff like area-screenshot, and calculator etc. My problem is that the key bindings I have set are being picked up by individual programs instead of acting upon the desktop

Comment: So the path you should look for is org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys

Comment: yes... I have gone to that location and there is nothing there

Comment: It should looks like the picture above.